# Set text over android google maps merkers

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

Any tips on how i can set Text Over android google maps (v2) default marker? for example i want to set the char 'A' inside(over) the marker (not snippest and not title).

Comment: do you want to show tooltip on marker??

Comment: its an option. do you have idea/tip/reference how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap( YOUR_MODIFIED_BITMAP ))
```

Where YOUR_MODIFIED_BITMAP is loaded bitmap with some custom content drawn with canvas on its top.
Hope it helps.